# rails, model naming question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a model called Chats. And I want to assign users to a discussion. They are either a part of the Chats or they aren't...

So I create one model Chats.

What's the standard Rails naming convention for the other table?

ChatUsers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While `has_and_belongs_to_many` is an ok option here, I recommend going with `has_many :through` instead.

In essence you will have an explicit join model, which you can call something like `ChatSession`.

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chat_sessions
  has_many :users, :through => :chat_sessions
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chat_sessions
  has_many :chats, :through => :chat_sessions
end

class ChatSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :chat
end
```

Now you will need a table called `chat_sessions` with columns :user_id, and :chat_id in it. This is your join table.

### Advantage

You get a model which is fully under your control, and isn't just a dumb join table managed by rails. So for example, if you want to track number of messages particular user left in particular chat, it could be a column in `chat_sessions` table. Presence of `:through` renders `habtm` unneeded in most cases. There is no complexity overhead either.

Comment: What about ChatParticipations, is that fine?

Comment: Absolutely, it's probably better in case there will be other types of participations. You may be able to find a better word too. For example `ChatSessions` would probably be the most accurate description, in accordance with web terminology. I'll even edit my answer with that.

Comment: so I do: rails generate scaffold ChatParticipants user_id:integer chat_id:integer    is that right??

Comment: First of all, the join model is not a "participant", it's a "participation". You are trying to name something that binds user to a chat, so it's session or participation. Second of all, you don't need a scaffold for that, it's just a join model. You don't need a whole form, full blown controller, views, etc. But the column names and types are correct, yes.

Comment: So is it just rails generate model?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a join table, it would be both table names joined by '_' and in alphabetical order of table names:

```
chats_users
```

Comment: it would be chats_users (both table names are plural) it helps to think of it this way => chats_users table is a join between chats and users tables

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [has_and_belongs_to_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) in rails. You basically have two models that call `has_and_belongs_to_many` and create a linking table that uses the two models in the name (alphabetical and plural).

models:

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :chats
end
```

Then your tables would be

1. chats
2. users
3. chats_users